# Are there recipes or cookbooks out there for the Kingkiller Chronicles?

Tags: food, the-kingkiller-chronicle

Does anybody know of any recipes or cookbooks based on food in the Kingkiller Chronicles? I've scoured the Internet and haven't found anything, but many eyes/brains are better than one!

I'm thinking of starting a food blog for real-world recipes based on fictional foods, and because the Kingkiller Chronicles are my favorite I thought I would start experimenting there, but I don't want to steal anybody's thunder or reproduce foods that are already commonplace.

Comment: Not offhand, most of the stuff I've heard of third hand is attempts to construct either games or songs.  Honestly I don't even recall a single dish; Kvothe is more descriptive in his drinking.  Is there anything that leaps to mind?

Comment: There are cookbooks for a number of fantasy settings such as Harry Potter, Song of Ice and Fire, Hunger Games (Irony anyone?), and the Lord of the Rings. But I found nothing for Kingkiller.

Comment: I think there are a lot of different stews and breads that are described in Kvothe's life as well as the food that Kote serves in his inn. I haven't re-read the series recently but I remember wanting to curl up with a thick stew at one point!

Answer (score 2):

There are no recipes for food that I know of from the kingkiller chronicles. However, there is a recipe for the alcoholic drink Metheglin if you're into brewing. The recipe can be found [here](http://blog.patrickrothfuss.com/?s=metheglin&searchsubmit=Search) in Pats blog. Be sure to check through the comments as some people there figured out some of Pats unknown ingredients.

Comment: Great! I knew he posted his recipe, but I didn't know that others commented the unknown ingredients... Thanks!